# Recursion with the IO and State monads

Tags: haskell, io, monads

I'm trying to implement a game in Haskell. I have a GameState type that manages things like the score, the players, and the rounds, where rounds are a RoundState type that manages the details of the game. To play the game, I have a function

```
playGame :: (RandomGen g) => State (GameState g) (Player, Int)
playGame = do playRound
              winner <- checkForWinner
              case winner of 
                  Nothing -> playGame
                  Just x -> return x
```

where

```
checkForWinner :: RandomGen g => State (GameState g) (Maybe (Player, Int))
playRound :: RandomGen (g) => State (GameState g) ()
```

This isn't very interesting though, because I can't output anything to the screen without the IO monad.

How can I wrap this function in the IO monad while keeping the recursion on playGame?

Comment: Could you add your imports, and types for `Player` and `GameState` so that others can first of all compile your code, please?

Comment: You'll need `Monad Transformers`, sepcifically `StateT`, check you can find an example [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Simple_StateT_use)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently your monad is just state, no `IO`:

```
State (GameState g)
```

What you want is a monad with state and IO:

```
type Game g = StateT (GameState g) IO
```

And now you can use the monad as you might expect

```
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)

-- ...

playGame :: (RandomGen g) => Game g (Player, Int)
playGame = do
    liftIO $ putStrLn "Look, I have IO"
    winner <- checkForWinner
    ...
```